# position of t[i] — * What[j] did Ann wonder who[i] would eat t[i] t[j]?

Tags: syntax

**(infelicitous) What*j* did Ann wonder who*i* would eat t*i* t*j* ?** (source: Key Terms in Syntax and Syntactic Theory)

The above sentence appears in a section discussing island constraint. I know this sentence is wrong as **what*j*** is moved out of the who-island, from **trace *j***, but my question here is about the positioning of **trace *i***. If the location of **trace *i*** is right, you are seeing 'eat (somebody) (something),' which is a strange construct. Do you think this is a typo; **t*i*** should be placed between 'would' and 'eat'? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know whether it's a typo, but I agree with you that it's a mistake.  Trace i is the logical subject of "eat" or "would eat", not its object.

Comment: Greg, thanks. Strictly speaking, trace i should come right in front of 'eat'; as a result of placing 'would,' whoi then moves up before the auxiliary, I think.